# how to get all pins on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function geocodeAddress(obj) {
    geocoder.geocode({ address: obj.Address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var p = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat = p.lat();
            var lng = p.lng();
            createMarker(obj, lat, lng);
        }
        else {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                nextAddress--;
                delay++;
            }
        }
    });
}
var marker, i;
function createMarker(objRDI, lat, lng) {
    //var contentString = add;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent();
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } 
    })(marker, i));

    bounds.extend(marker.position);
    iconCounter++;

    if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

This is my code.When i debug the the code in this line
geocoder.geocode({ address: obj.Address }, function (results, status) {

I got address but result is null. but when i copy the address and check this address is valid or not .this address is valid and give me longitude and latitude. please suggest me what the issue here why result is come null .how to resolve this.

Comment: What does `obj.Address` look like?

Comment: What is the value of the `status`?  _"when i copy the address and check this address is valid or not .this address is valid"_ - how do you check it's valid?

Comment: I checked this address  google where address convert in log and lat. i got lat and log.status comes over query limit.

Comment: Well that's your problem, you're over your query limit.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#quotas  Assuming you're not on the premium plan, you can make _"2,500 free requests per day"_